# Source of wishing "Titchadesh" - תתחדש on new clothes

Tags: minhag, blessing, clothing

What is the source for wishing someone "תתחדש" for a new item of clothing?

See [the Rema OC:224](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.223.6?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) who brings a minhag to wish someone that bought new clothes "תבלה ותחדש". Literal translation is "You should wear it out and renew it" which I would consider to be the rough equivalent of "Use it in good health". Basically you are wishing the proud owner of the new item to put it to good use.

Where did the prevalent custom to simply say "תתחדש" ("Titchadesh") come from? It simply doesn't make sense.. the word literally means - I think - "you should renew yourself". Is this another type of well-wishing (and what does it mean) or is it related to the Rema above?

Comment: I hear them saying it in Israel

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's only meant to be a shorted version of the original (in which תתחדש refers to the renewal of the new item, not the person).

Comment: @mtl I disagree. The language is different. תתחדש is in hitpa'el implying a reflexive verb meaning "it should renew itself". I don't know if the "it" refers to the clothing somehow renewing itself, or the person renewing himself by wearing the clothing. Regardless, the colloquial term is not the same as Rama's phrasing.

Comment: @DanF Just because it looks and is pronounced like a *hitpa'el* conjugation does not mean that it really is one. It could very well be a portmanteau like MTL suggests.